# Internal Server Error for admin login and dashboard

Tags: craft3, admin, server

I deployed a Craft 3 site and the site is fine, however when I try and go to /admin to login I get a Craft "Internal Server Error - Server Error" message and can't access the dashboard.
Any ideas where to look?

Thank you!

Comment: If it's a Craft-styled Internal Server Error message, the underlying error will be in the `storage/logs` folder and that should help us debug.

Answer (score 2):

To get some ideas we'll need more information. I suggest

1. Go to storage/logs folder
2. Hit from that directory `tail -f *`
3. Then go to your chrome and try to access your : admin page
4. Go back to your tail -f you will see some error

Tell us more about the error your find.